# What does the parameter -c for netsh actually do?

Tags: netsh

The Microsoft Doc says "-c Optional. Specifies that netsh enters the specified netsh context."

I don't understand what the context means here.

Could anyone explain this parameter for me? I would appreciate it if examples could be given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows utility Netsh.exe can perform a number of tasks, covering a number of technologies, e.g.

- WFP  (Windows Filtering Platform)
- WinHTTP (Windows HTTP Library)
- Advfirewall (Windows Firewall)

Just run netsh to see them all and you can consider these contexts.

So in interactive mode, you can switch to a context with the -c switch, without actually running a command.  E.g.:

> netsh -c WinHTTP

This will switch to the WinHTTP context and do no more other than return the prompt:

> netsh winhhtp>

From there you can get/set a proxy for example or list the commands.

Once you know what you're doing, you probably don't need interactive mode and you can just run the commands directly, e.g.

> netsh winhttp reset proxy